# How to change product version with Electron Builder (Windows)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron, electron-builder

I am using Electron Builder to build an Electron app. I would like the executable to have a product version that is different from the `package.json` version.

This is what the `build` instruction in `package.json` looks like:

```json
"build": {
    "appId": "myAppId",
    "productName": "My App",
    "copyright": "Copyright (C) 2022 My Company",
    "artifactName": "My App.exe",
    "directories": {
        "output": "dist/My App"
    },
    "buildVersion": "1.0.0.1"
},
```

I thought that `buildVersion` would update the product version, but when I look at the details of the `.exe` file, the product version has remained the same as the version number in `package.json` (`1.0.0`):

[image: App details]

How can I solve this?

---

EDIT: As a workaround, I downloaded [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/verpatch) package, called `verpatch`, and I used its executable to change the product version of my application's `.exe` file:

```powershell
.\verpatch.exe "My App.exe" /va "1.0.0.1" /pv "1.0.0.1" /s copyright "Copyright (C) 2022 My Company" /s description "My App's Description" /s product "My App"
```

It would be nice, however, to be able to use Electron Builder for this, instead of an external package.

Comment: There's a way to override the product version, but it only works if the version is consist of 3 numbers.
You can try adding `extraMetadata` parameter to electron-builder configuration which will inject properties to package.json.
For example: `"extraMetadata": { "version": "2.0.0" }`

Comment: @JonathanTsai your answer has to be massively upvoted, since it's so hard to find this simple info!